# How to hit google oauth2 sign in API from backend?

Tags: java, api, google-signin

I am trying to implement google sign in server side and the API i am calling is **https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?** . If i directly call this from browser , it redirects me to my redirect_uri with code as request param but if i run it as rest webservice from backend , it dosent do anything although the response is 200

backend code:

```
public void oauth2Service(){
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    StringBuilder oauth2GetCodeUrl = new StringBuilder();
    oauth2GetCodeUrl.append(env.getProperty("oauth2_url"));
    oauth2GetCodeUrl.append("scope=").append(getGoogleSignInProperties.getScope());
    oauth2GetCodeUrl.append("&redirect_uri=").append(getGoogleSignInProperties.getRedirect_uri());
    oauth2GetCodeUrl.append("&response_type=").append(getGoogleSignInProperties.getResponse_id());
    oauth2GetCodeUrl.append("&client_id=").append(getGoogleSignInProperties.getClient_id());
    oauth2GetCodeUrl.append("&approval_prompt=").append(getGoogleSignInProperties.getApproval_prompt());

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(oauth2GetCodeUrl.toString()).get()
      .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
      .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
      .build();

    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the api should redirect me to my redirection URI already mentioned in the request

Response string is : Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?passive=1209600&continue=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope%3Demail%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp://localhost:8080/MovieSearch/webapi/googleOAuthCallback%26response_type%3Dcode%26client_id%3D52424919169-remgpb2h4nhdua57plc1cem4p0qo4if8.apps.googleusercontent.com%26approval_prompt%3Dforce%26from_login%3D1%26as%3DhYtl9Ra4jWxbygJmS2uAiw&followup=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope%3Demail%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp://localhost:8080/MovieSearch/webapi/googleOAuthCallback%26response_type%3Dcode%26client_id%3D52424919169-remgpb2h4nhdua57plc1cem4p0qo4if8.apps.googleusercontent.com%26approval_prompt%3Dforce%26from_login%3D1%26as%3DhYtl9Ra4jWxbygJmS2uAiw&oauth=1&sarp=1&scc=1}

Comment: `it dosent do anything although the response is 200` is very ambiguous. You need to provide more details.

Comment: it means it doesn't redirect me to the `redirect_uri` which is correct behavior

Comment: What does this print `response.toString()`?